# ASP.NET 4 - How to generate asp.net identity schema for database in SQL?

Tags: asp.net, entity-framework, asp.net-identity

I am using VS2019 16.10 to create an ASP.NET 4 application (.Net 4.7.2 - not MVC) and have set the option to use local authentication.  After generating the application it has not created the schema for the asproles, aspusers etc. tables in the database.

I have enabled migrations but all that got created is an empty seed() function in the migrations directory.

The NuGet package that was installed is `Microsoft.AspNet.Identity.EntityFramework` v2.2.3

Does anyone have a link to a SQL script that creates the schema?

I have tried a couple but get errors with missing columns.

Regards.

Answer (score 0):

Well, assuming you are running sql server x64, which is likely?

Then this path should work:

```
C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet_regsql.exe
```

Comment: Hi thanks,  I did try that as it was the old traditional way, but for some reason I got a lot of schema mismatch (column missing).  And yes, 64bit.  I have added a work-a-round as my solution to the issue below.

Answer (score 0):

The solution that I found the closest to work was to create a basic asp.net 2.1 project in Visual Studio which generated the migration.  I was then able to use the Package Console Manager to generate the database schema that could be run in SSMS.

The only issue was a missing column in the AspNetUsers table  LockoutEndDateUtc which I added manually.